# Problem with PHP, libncursesw and Arch

Tags: arch-linux, php, libraries

After doing a system upgrade, whenever trying to use php it complains:

```
php: error while loading shared libraries: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Sure, it's because I now have libncursesw.so.6

Any workaround?

Comment: I installed PHP from source. I deleted all the files but I still get the same error message.

Comment: ncurses in arch is now version 6, you'll need to recompile your PHP installation to link against the new library files.

Answer (score 1):

I had not upgraded my Arch server in a few weeks: ncurses has indeed changed to version 6 as of early September, but PHP should have been upgraded with it.

The quick-n-dirty fix is: `pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/ncurses-5.9-7-i686.pkg.tar.xz`

You can install PHP via `pacman`. There'a a number of pieces that I've found necessary, including `php`, `php-apache`, `php-gd`, `php-sqlite`.  If you're compiling PHP from source to stay at a particular version, I'm not sure that's a good idea as PHP gets patched a lot. It would be hard to keep up with the security patches compiling everything yourself.